# I was going to see / I should've seen / I would've seen

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A: Have you seen your kids recently?

B: No. **I was going to see** / **I should've seen** / **I would've seen** them last weekend, but I canceled.

1. Without more context, which of these would be more likely?
2. Which one should I use if there was an agreement, and if I don't want B to show bad conscience for canceling even though he maybe does have?

Comment: There is also **I was supposed to see them**. I don't know which is the most likely - have you tried Google Ngrams?

Comment: I'm confused—I distinctly remember this question from a few days ago, but can't find it now. Was it deleted? Anyway: There's no such thing as "without more context." What I mean is, real conversations have real context, and meaning depends on it. Take away the context and we can't say anything definite about meaning.

Comment: I have tried Google Ngram viewer, but it's hard to know which one of them would be more likely in my context.

Comment: The question you think about had a similar dialog but focused on another part of it, I believe. I didn't delete it.

Comment: Just ignore the first question then.

Comment: They all mean different things. How can we know what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping point 2 in mind (I don't want B to show bad conscience for cancelling), I would probably use `No. I was going to see them last week, but I cancelled.` `I should've seen` them reflects guilt, and `I would've seen them` reflects *even more* guilt...